# IntelliJ gives Unnecessary qualified reference warning in build.gradle file

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I'm looking to resolve a bunch of errors I have in my gradle files in IntelliJ. One of the issues I have is "Unnecessary qualified reference". I know that means I can use import xyz instead of putting the full class path but if I try and do this in the build.gradle file IntelliJ will remove the import on me for some reason.

One example is:

```
wrapper {
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}
```

In this code Wrapper.DistributionType is marked as being unncessary but if I try and apply the inspection rule to import the reference it doesn't do it. If I type out import import org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper.DistributionType then IntelliJ will remove it for me.

Is this an inspection that just shouldn't apply to gradle files and should be removed?

Comment: But in this code the `Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL` is actually not used -- it's an expression but there's no method call or assignment here. Didn't you mean `wrapper { distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL }`?

Comment: @wasyl, sorry added the distribution type. Should have copied the code snippet instead of typing it out by hand